# How can multiple users simultaneously edit an Adobe Acrobat PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, editing, multiple-users

Is it possible for multiple users to simultaneously add call-outs, comments, and text boxes to a PDF in Adobe Acrobat? We have a PDF printout of a web portal that has been marked up by our supervising engineer--three of us will be addressing the markups at the same time (there are a lot of markups).

Anytime a markup is addressed, we will be adding an **Addressed** call-out or adding a sticky note to explain in detail the changes that were made. To prevent overlap, we would like to simultaneously edit the PDF so we see each other's **Addressed** markups.

This feature is available in BlueBeam Revu; however our office does not carry any BlueBeam licenses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Send for Shared Commenting" using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC then Reader users can participate. When hosted on a compatible server... like a webDAV server or SharePoint, multiple users can comment at the same time. The comments will synchronize automatically or you can trigger it to sync manually. Everyone will see everyone else's comments and can reply to them.

[image]

Comment: ...or any WebDAV capable server. This one has a free version and it works well for me. https://deveo.com/

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get all the way through but was blocked due to my lack of admin privileges, but I can resolve that myself.